# How can I render an entire UICollectionView into a PDF (in Swift), rather than just the part that was on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I have a `UICollectionView` which scrolls through multiple pages. I want to put the entire collection view into PDF form, whereas now, all I get in PDF form is the part of the collection view that was last on the screen. The code is:

```
    func createPdfFile() -> URL?
    {
        if let myView = myView {

            let pdfData = NSMutableData()
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myView.bounds, nil)
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
            myView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
            let fileName = "temp.pdf"
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            if pdfData.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true) {
                print("Successfully wrote to \(fileURL)")
                return fileURL
            }
            else {

                return nil
            }
        }
        else {
            DLog("Error: Could not create pdf")
            return nil
        }
    }


     func printView() {
        if let fileURL = createPdfFile() {
            let webView = UIWebView()
            webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:
fileURL))
            self.view = webView
        }
        else {
            DLog("Error: Could not print the pdf. Write to disk failed.")
            alertOk("Failed to generate PDF.", title: "Error")
        }
    }
```

How can I get it to render *all* of the view into a PDF?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?